# Report of Event GA4 not display detail?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I had add GA4 to a button in my site:

```
gtag('event', 'Search KeyWords', {            
            'Keyword': keyword  // param
         });
```

In RealTime Report of GA4 , It can display detail of Search KeyWords:
[image]
[image]

In Engagement -> Event Report of GA4: not display detail of Search KeyWords:
[image]
[image]

Why does Report of Event GA4 not display detail Information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see those event parameters in GA4 user interface, you need to [create custom dimension](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/a-guide-to-custom-dimensions-in-google-analytics-4/#process) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check it later because Google thresholds your reports because lack of data and only 6 occurrences in the checking period. However, your reports will appear with more results. You can also check search keywords in real-time using BigQuery instead.

Comment: Google thresholds it showing in report "Event count
 by Gender", My problem GA4 it not show detail information of each Keyword (in Realtime it had can show https://i.stack.imgur.com/niUAl.png )